# Error assigning a dateadd expression using 'nanosecond' to a variable in SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dateadd

I am trying to assign the result of a dateadd expression to a variable in a Snowflake sql script.

The assignment works fine when I use any date_or_time_part **EXCEPT nanosecond**.  When I use nanosecond, I get the following error:

```
Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'**
```

Is there a reason nanosecond behaves differently, or is this a bug?

```
-- 'second' is successfully set into the variable
set foo = dateadd("second"    , -1, '2019-10-25');

-- 'nanosecond' throws an error:
-- Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'.
set bar = dateadd("nanosecond", -1, '2019-10-25');
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug.  I will raise it internally at Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a current limitation of Snowflake.

Today, in `set` expressions the right side is supposed to be a simple expression, for which there's a "fast" computation path (not to get too much into details). For "second", such a path exists, for "nanosecond", it doesn't.

You can work around this by making the right expression a "subquery" expression, like this:

```
set x = (select dateadd(nanosecond, -1, '2019-10-25'));
```

Comment: This is a good workaround to my mind- the [snowflake community forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008Jn723SAB/unsupported-feature-assignment-from-nonconstant-source-expression) recommends this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug,

```
select dateadd("nanosecond", -1, '2019-10-25') from dual
```

seems to work just fine and at the same time the data type is the same both for second and nanosecond - the date us converted to TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) so no difference there either.